# How do I add text data labels from a list to matplotlib chart?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have built a scatter plot showing the Total Number of Facebook Likes vs. the Attendance at a list of Sporting Events.  The datapoints are labeled with "#of likes, total attendance."

I'd like to alter the data labels so that they show instead the NAME of each event.  I have all of the event names stored in a variable called `Themes`.  This variable was created by pulling the event names from a column in a pandas dataframe.  Here is my code:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

A = Likes
B = Attendance

plt.plot(A,B, "o")
for xy in zip(A, B):      
    ax.annotate('(%s, %s)' % xy, xy=xy, textcoords='data')

plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

How can I alter the label portion of this code to replace the #of likes, total attendance with the names of each event from my variable `Themes`?

Comment: Just replace what you put in the label??? what is wrong with that?

Comment: I'm asking how to do that.  If I just change the code in line 8 to read:
    ax.annotate('(Themes)', xy=xy, textcoords='data')   the labels disappear completely.  I've tried other combinations and get a variety of errors.  Nothing I've tried will take the event names contained in Themes and add them to the individual datapoints.

Comment: For your next questions. it's always good to show what you've tried in your post, it shows your efforts + shows exactly what you are doing wrong.

Comment: Thanks--I'm a total newb, so things that are probably really obvious to experienced developers are mystifying to me still.  I just tried this:  ax.annotate(N, xy=xy, textcoords='data')  and it put the ENTIRE list of names next to each datapoint, instead of iterating through the list.

Comment: But have you tried my answer? It should be iterating through the names by including `Themes` in the `zip` function.

Comment: Yes--it worked like a charm.  Thank you!  If you downvoted my question, would you mind undoing that?  I am afraid I am in danger of losing access to the community.

Comment: I don't think you'll loose access because of a downvote or two. I think people get kicked out only for being rude, spamming or having a repeated collection of *terrible* questions. I've had a few downvotes myself when I started using SO, and I'm still here. I guess it's just part of the learning process :) But FYI I would not have downvoted if you had included the info in your first two comments, which was your actual problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
plt.plot(Likes, Attendance, "o")
for (likes, attendance, theme) in zip(Likes, Attendance, Themes):      
    ax.annotate(theme, xy=(likes, attendance), textcoords='data')
```